# Numpy - Calculate element wise mean for a 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mean, elementwise-operations

I found multible questions with similar titles but they didn't match with my case.

I have a np.array with offset values and I want the mean value for index from all previous values.

My first approach was with a for loop, but with huge arrays it is obviously way to slow.

```
offset = np.array([2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10])
mean_mraw = []

for i, ofs in enumerate(offset):
        mean_mraw.append(offset[0:i+1].mean())
```

So what I expect is this:

```
mean_mraw = [2, 3, 3.6, 4.5, 5.2, 6] #np.array
```

Is there np- build in function for that or how could I solve that in another way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the cumulated sum (`np.cumsum`) and divide by the number of seen elements (using `np.arange`):

```
a = np.array([2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10])
out = np.cumsum(a)/(np.arange(a.shape[0])+1)
```

output:

```
array([2.        , 3.        , 3.66666667, 4.5       , 5.2       ,
       6.        ])
```